# how to create a user profile page with firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

is it possible to creat a user profile page in android native without using any other SQL database because i am not good with JSON.

i want to creat two activities one will show a profile page to the logged in user( firebase auth) and for the other users
the second layout will be for editing the profile and the ability to add a profile picture, full name, age and adresse( i used firebase phone auth so no need to use an email adresse or a password).

i tried to get the user id and store it to firestore in a new collection with the other proprties but it did not worked for me.

Comment: What would you like to use, Firebase real-time database or Cloud Firestore? Are you interested in a new answer?

Comment: i am doing it with cloud firestore
i will post an update when i finish it

Comment: Will you provide an answer?

Comment: yes for sure i will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create document in Firestore like this

```
DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection(userId).document("Profile");

    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Profile exist");
                getProfileData();
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "Profile is not exist");
                firebaseFirestore.collection(userId).document("Profile").set(profileEntity);
            }
        }
    });
```

If profile document is not exist, it will create new one.
Store the data in profile entity and save against the profile document.

If profile document exist:

```
private void getProfileData() {
    DocumentReference docRef = firebaseFirestore.collection(userId).document("Profile");
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                if (document != null) {
                    ProfileEntity profileEntity = task.getResult().toObject(ProfileEntity.class);

                    if (profileEntity != null) {
                       //show your profile data
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: next step is to store all the fields on that collection?

Answer (score 1):

What you may try is, that you can setup the Firebase Realtime Database and store the values in it, like for example: username, imageURL, age and address.

After you have got the input of all these (I am guessing you can get this done, yourself). You can store the details in a `users` child in your Firebase database, using the following code:

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("users");
DatabaseRefrence detailRef = ref.child(userName);
detailRef.child("age").setValue(age);
detailRef.child("imageURL").setValue(imageURL);
detailRef.child("address").setValue(address);
```

To access and show the data above in the second activity, you have to use `event-listeners`, as follows:

```java
// for example you have to read and show the address of the user from database

userRef.child(Current_userName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String address = dataSnapshot.child("address").getValue(String.class);


                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

You can do this to read all the data and display them in your profile activity.
For the activity where you want them to edit this data, you can get their input and use `Maps` to update all the values in database, like this:

```java
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String identifier = userName;

                Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                values.put("address", address);
                values.put("age",age);
                values.put("imageURL",newImageURL);

                userRef.child(identifier).updateChildren(values);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

This will also trigger the listeners in your profile class and they will be updated accordingly.